# How to use jQuery to traverse through a set of elements and set odd/even classes?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of elements like this:

```
<div class="odd">1</div>
<div class="even">2</div>
<div class="odd">3</div>
<div class="even">4</div>
```

Now, when user erases the element 3, the result is:

```
<div class="odd">1</div>
<div class="even">2</div>
<div class="even">4</div>
```

Now I want jQuery to go from first to last element and redefine classes:

```
<div class="odd">1</div>
<div class="even">2</div>
<div class="odd">4</div>
```

I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:odd` and `:even` selectors:

```
var $divs = $('div');

$divs.filter(':odd').attr('class', 'odd');
$divs.filter(':even').attr('class', 'even');
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
$("div").removeClass('odd even');
$("div:odd").addClass('odd');
$("div:even").addClass('even');
```

By only removing the .odd or .even class, any additional classes you add (besides .odd and .even) will 'survive'.

Comment: +1 more elegant to add/remove only the needed classes without reseting the whole class attribute of the element

Comment: @Pandaiolo Creating 3 jQuery objects for selecting same elements is not that elegant.

Comment: approved... for the general case (where you dont know if other classes are present), I would apply your element caching in addition to c_kick  code ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
$('div:odd').attr('class', 'odd');
$('div:even').attr('class', 'even');
```

JsFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2VpgV/

Answer (score 0):

You should use *[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)*|:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Below is an example of event delegation mechanism:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#container').on('click', '.btn', function(e){
           $(this).parent().nextAll().each(function(i,el){
             var $t = $(this);
               $t.attr('class', $t.is('.odd') ? 'even':'odd');
           }).end().remove();
    });
});
```

```css
.odd{background-color:red}
.even{background-color:green}
.btn{text-decoration:underline;font-style:italic;padding:2px;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;margin:2px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="odd">
    1<span class="btn" title="remove the line and fix siblings class">remove line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="even">
    2<span class="btn" title="remove the line and fix siblings class">remove line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="odd">
    3<span class="btn" title="remove the line and fix siblings class">remove line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="even">
    4<span class="btn" title="remove the line and fix siblings class">remove line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="odd">
    5<span class="btn" title="remove the line and fix siblings class">remove line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="even">
    6<span class="btn" title="remove the line and fix siblings class">remove line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="odd">
    7<span class="btn" title="remove the line and fix siblings class">remove line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="even">
    8<span class="btn" title="remove the line and fix siblings class">remove line</span>
  </div>
</div>
```